# Is it possible to chain key binding commands in sublime text 2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

There are times in Sublime Text when I want to reveal the current file in the side bar and then navigate around the folder structure.

This can be achieved using the commands `reveal_in_side_bar` and `focus_side_bar` however they have to be bound to two separate key combinations so I have to do 2 keyboard combinations to achieve my goal when ideally I'd like just one (I'm lazy).

Is there any way to bind multiple commands to a single key combination? e.g. something like this:

```
{
  "keys": ["alt+shift+l"], 
  "commands": ["reveal_in_side_bar", "focus_side_bar"]
},
```

### Solution

Based on @artem-ivanyk's and @d_rail's answers

**1) Tools → New Plugin**

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class RevealInSideBarAndFocusCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("reveal_in_side_bar")
        self.window.run_command("focus_side_bar")
```

Save as RevealInSideBarAndFocus.py

**2) Sublime Text 2 → Preferences → Key Bindings — User**

Bind it to shortcut:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+l"], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar_and_focus" }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Updating @Artem Ivanyk's answer.  I do not know what changed in Sublime, but that solution did not work for me, but I got this to work:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class RevealInSideBarAndFocusCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("reveal_in_side_bar")
        self.window.run_command("focus_side_bar")
```

.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+8"], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar_and_focus" }
```

Btw, I'm using Build 2220

Comment: working on v2.0.1 Build 2217. Please save the filename as `RevealInSideBarAndFocus.py`

Comment: I don't think file name matters, does it?

Comment: Not from my experience, but location and class name do.  The `"command"` is the CamelCased python class converted to underscores.  Also, save in *Packages/CustomCommand* folder, not in *Packages/User*.

Answer (score 36):

Although the question is a year old, this might help people that are still looking for an answer.

Recently, a new package was developed by jisaacks, called `Chain of command`. It has the primary task to do exactly what you request, to chain several commands at once.

The package can be found here:
https://github.com/jisaacks/ChainOfCommand

An example of the working can be found below.

Let's say you wanted a key binding to duplicate the current file. You could set this key binding:

```
{
  "keys": ["super+shift+option+d"], 
  "command": "chain", 
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      ["select_all"],
      ["copy"],
      ["new_file"],
      ["paste"],
      ["save"]
    ]
  }
}
```

This would select all the text, copy it, create a new file, paste the text, then open the save file dialog.

Source: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Chain%20of%20Command.

Comment: I'm in Debian with Sublime 3 Build 3126. This plugin does not seem to work, advice pls.

Comment: Works like magic. Use it for commands with arguments just omit `"args":`. E.g. `["set_file_type", {"syntax": "PostgreSQL.tmLanguage"}]`

Comment: A good solution for those not wanting to make their own plugins.

Comment: sublimetext 3 it doesn't work, i tried with `{
  "keys": ["ctrl+v"], 
  "command": "chain", 
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      ["paste"],
      ["reindent"]
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 26):

Stumbled upon similar problem. When trying to record macros, which involved *„Save“* command, console threw at me  *„Unknown macros command save“* message.
Worked my way around with elementary plugin.

**1)** **Tools → New Plugin**

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class MyChainedActionsCommand():
    def run(self):
        self.view.run_command("reveal_in_side_bar")
        self.view.run_command("focus_side_bar")
```

You need to use upper camel case notation for the class name. ST2 exposes this class for the command name with *„Command“* suffix removed and the rest converted into the lowercase-underscore notation. I.e. in this example `MyChainedActionsCommand` could be run in sublime's console typing: `view.run_command("my_chained_actions")`

**2)** **Sublime Text 2 → Preferences → Key Bindings — User**

Bind it to shortcut:

`{ "keys": ["alt+shift+l"], "command": "my_chained_actions" }`

Heed commas.

Comment: The code deos nothing in version 2.0.1 build 2217; No matter, whether it's `MyChainedActionsCommand()` or `MyChainedActionsCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand)` or whatever.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nilium/3327730).

I've been trying to implement this in a long time and found this by accident.

Don't forget to read the "documentation" provided. I kept trying to make this work, until I reallized I was not passing the "context" key.

Comment: This gist is awesome. Thank you for sharing the link. +1 Ps.: I actually didn't used context, I simply omitted it and my key bind worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a macro to do this.  For Sublime Text, macros are essentially just chained commands.  You then create a keybinding for that macro.  You can create a macro by using `Tools > Record Macro`, then executing your commands (beware that macros record keystrokes as well, so you'll want to use the commands from the menu bar to not cause conflicts), then `Stop Recording`, then `Save Macro`.  After you save the macro, you can open it back up in Sublime Text to make sure that it recorded only what you want.

Comment: I've set up a macro, however it's saying "Unknown macro command reveal_in_side_bar" in the console (Says the same fir focus_side_bar). Is there a way to reference existing commands from inside a macro?

Comment: Hmm. ST2's macros seem to be picky as to what they will and will not record/accept as valid commands.  If that's the case, you'll have to make a plugin that chains these commands using run_command().  It's not as complicated as it sounds.  I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Artem Ivanyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863489/2503795) reply, here is a version of ChainedActions that works with arguments. It takes two arguments for `actions` and `args`. Both are lists and each command in the list gets executed with the corresponding arguments. This admittedly stupid example inserts two snippets: `view.run_command("chained_actions", {"actions":["insert_snippet","insert_snippet"],"args":[{"contents": "`($0)"},{"contents": "1($0)"}]})`

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class ChainedActionsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, actions, args):
        for i, action in enumerate(actions):
            self.view.run_command(action, args[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to use the same command but I ended up with a bug that when the file's folder was already unfolded sublime moved my focus sidebar's top, where I can see the open files. To improve this behavior I've wrote a new plugin that ensures it'll behave as I want to, here it is https://github.com/miguelgraz/FocusFileOnSidebar

Answer (score 1):

I am using Sublime text3 build - 3083. It solves the problem just by 'Reveal it in side bar', the focus comes automatically.

I have added a custom keyboard shortcut for 'Reveal in sidebar' by adding the following statement under Preferences->Key Bindings-User :

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reveal_in_side_bar"}
]
```

The option - 'Reveal in sidebar' was missing for **image** file types, since the context menu doesn't appear with the right click of the mouse. The custom keyboard shortcut comes handy in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Sublime Text Build 4103 the feature is supported natively:

"Added the `chain` command, which accepts a list of commands to run in its "commands" argument. This allows binding a key to run multiple commands without having to use a macro"

See Changelog on https://www.sublimetext.com/dev