# multiple "commands" in a single Sublime Text 2 user keymap shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, keymapping, sublimetext4

Is there a way to have multiple "commands" associated with one shortcut?

I have these two shortcuts. First shortcut makes the window on the left larger than the right one (in a 2 column view) and the next shortcut puts the focus on the first window. I tend to forget one or the other shortcut when coding quickly.

```
{
    "keys": ["super+alt+left"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.66, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    }
},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+left"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 0 } }
```

This question makes me sound like i'm lazy but i'd like to think of it as being efficient.

Any advice or suggestions, please?

Comment: Funny how I found this question, wanting to do the exact same sequence of commands.

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 37):

As of *Sublime Text 4 (build 4104, 3 May 2021)* you can use the built in `chain` command.

In older versions (ST2 or ST3) you needed to install the [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) plugin ([GitHub](https://github.com/jisaacks/ChainOfCommand)).

Both have the same syntax, allowing you write keybindings etc that perform multiple actions, e.g.:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"],
  "context": [
    { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
  ],
  "command": "chain",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      ["hide_panel", {"cancel": true}],
      ["find_under_expand"]
    ]
  }
},
```

which redefines Ctrl+D so that it'll close the Find panel if it's open, then perform its normal action (Quick Add Next).

You can do any number of subcommands. Each is an array with the command name (e.g. `"hide_panel"`) followed optionally by the arguments (e.g. `{"cancel": true}`). The unofficial/incomplete [documentation of available commands and their arguments](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/commands.html) may be helpful.

Comment: This plugin deserve more stars

Comment: Awesome plugin, this should be marked as the answer

Comment: **Note:** For anyone just learning sublime, you can also attach multiple commands to a custom class in a plugin you write yourself, such as `class MyCustomCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand)` which you can write in python. See [your-first-plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html?highlight=custom%20plugin#your-first-plugin)

Answer (score 14):

There's a post on the [Sublime Text 2 forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8677) that includes code for a generic "run multiple commands" plugin. It will allow you to bind multiple commands to any key binding the same way you'd normally bind them to one:

```
  {
    "keys": ["super+alt+left"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        { "command": "set_layout", "args": { "cols": [0.0, 0.66, 1.0], "rows": [0.0, 1.0], "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]] } },
        { "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 0 } }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Note that this is untested, and **you must install the plugin provided in the post** for this to work.

Alternatively, you can create a plugin for a specific set of commands following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863489/1684247).

Comment: For these very commands, `"context": "window"` must be added as well. For example: `{ "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 0 }, "context": "window" }`.

Answer (score 8):

You can record a macro (using the Tools menu), then save it and set a keyboard shortcut to call it using

```
{"keys": ["super+alt+l"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/Example.sublime-macro"}}
```

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html

Granted, this isn't quite what you're asking for, but may provide the same end for others with similar questions.