# How can I open the current file in a new pane in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to split a panel in two and open the current file in the new pane? I used to believe that `alt+shift+2` would do the job. But it isn't working for me. How can I do it?

Comment: "*It isn't working for me*" is incredibly vague and unhelpful. Instead, describe **exactly** what is happening and *not* happening, using as much detail and being as clear and precise as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple key bindings for that. Based on the file containing the default key-bindings:

1. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>: set two column layout and focus on second group (currently empty second column).
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>: focus on first group.
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>: move current file to second group (right column).

If you want to do it with a unique key-binding you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646552/is-it-possible-to-chain-key-binding-commands-in-sublime-text-2) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388477/multiple-commands-in-a-single-sublime-text-2-user-keymap-shortcut) question and others that explain how to use a unique key-binding containing multiple commands.

Note: the given key-bindings work under Linux. Key-bidings on Windows or OS X may be different.

Comment: thank you. ctrl + shift +2. that is what I was looking for