# Sublime Text 3 Settings: Save Twice

Tags: sublimetext3, livereload

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this or not, if it's not please let me know where would be the right place.

There is a well known issue with LiveReload for Sublime Text in which the changes are not shown unless you save twice.

I'm wondering if there is a way to edit the settings to have ST automatically save twice when you hit save.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default keybinding to instead save twice. In order to do that you will need a way to call the "save" command more than once. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27994582/3259320) tells how to do that. Basically, install the [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) package so that you may call the custom "chain" command, which will run the commands you pass as an array of `args`. This will allow you to define your new keybinding in your keybindings file.

**Default (OSX).sublime-keymap — User**

```
{ "keys": ["super+s"], 
  "command": "chain",   
  "args": {
     "commands": [
       ["save"],
       ["save"]
     ]
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I put those commands into the keybindings section and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @ActuallyHelpsPeople Does the example keybinding they provide on the package control page I linked work when you put that in?

Comment: Nope, no joy I'm afraid. :(

Comment: @ActuallyHelpsPeople Hmm, that works for me so something is wrong with your Chain of Command installation. Are you sure you installed it correctly?

Comment: I went into package control>Install package>chain of command. Once it was done I restarted and I don't see it anymore in the install package list, but I don't see it under Prefs either

Comment: @ActuallyHelpsPeople Try reinstalling it; I'm not really sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: Still no dice I'm afraid :(