# need to save twice to save a file in sublime text 3, why?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Mac OS.

When I save a file by clicking `command+s` **once** then the file is not saved.
I have to click `command+s` **twice** to save the file.

I'm wondering why this happening?
Is there a conf. to change this behavior?

I'd like to click `command+s` **once** ( not twice ) to save a file in sublime text3.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004829/sublime-text-3-settings-save-twice) maybe its the same issue

Comment: First guess would be a key binding you or a package has added to do this for whatever reason. Second guess would be a package that does something on save that changes the file and makes it dirty again.