# How can I trigger auto-complete when typing `(` using `auto_complete_triggers`

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am having problems triggering autocomplete when I type `(`. Other characters work perfectly fine. Here is the code in my syntex-specific setting file:

```
"auto_complete_triggers": [  
    {"selector": "source.r - string - comment", "characters": "("},
    {"selector": "source.r - string - comment", "characters": ","}
]
```

Now `,` triggers autocomplete but `(` does not. When I change `(` to other characters it also works. Why does `(` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that `(` gets somehow overwritten by a snippet for entering the closing `)`. So I come up with this solution based a key binding that chains together the snippet and the auto complete.

First, a command to chain commands:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/10863489/2503795
import sublime_plugin

class ChainedActionsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, actions, args):
        for i, action in enumerate(actions):
            self.view.run_command(action, args[i])
```

Second, the keybinding, which first inserts the snippet and then starts auto_complete

```
{
    "keys": ["("],
    "command": "chained_actions",
    "args": {
        "actions":["insert_snippet","auto_complete"],
        "args":[{"contents": "(${0:$SELECTION})"},{}]
    },
    "context": [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.r"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try escaping the `(` with a `\` character:

```json
"auto_complete_triggers": [  
    {"selector": "source.r - string - comment", "characters": "\("},
    {"selector": "source.r - string - comment", "characters": ","}
]
```

This may allow the interpreter to "see" the `(` and not think it's part of the JSON syntax.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but unfortunately it doesn't work. I think the problem is that `(` is connected to a snippet that inserts `($1)`...