# Save file before running custom command in Sublime3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimerepl

This question is similar to this one [Is it possible to chain key binding commands in sublime text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9646552/1391441) Some years have passed since that question (and the answers given), and I'm using Sublime Text 3 (not 2), so I believe this new question is justified.

I've setup a custom keybind:

```
{
    "keys": ["f5"],
    "command": "project_venv_repl"
}
```

to run the `project_venv_repl.py` script:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ProjectVenvReplCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    Starts a SublimeREPL, attempting to use project's specified
    python interpreter.

    Instructions to make this file work taken from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002696/1391441
    """

    def run(self, edit, open_file='$file'):
        """Called on project_venv_repl command"""
        cmd_list = [self.get_project_interpreter(), '-i', '-u']

        if open_file:
            cmd_list.append(open_file)

        self.repl_open(cmd_list=cmd_list)

    def get_project_interpreter(self):
        """Return the project's specified python interpreter, if any"""
        settings = self.view.settings()
        return settings.get('python_interpreter', '/usr/bin/python')

    def repl_open(self, cmd_list):
        """Open a SublimeREPL using provided commands"""
        self.view.window().run_command(
            'repl_open', {
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'type': 'subprocess',
                'cmd': cmd_list,
                'cwd': '$file_path',
                'syntax': 'Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage'
            }
        )
```

This runs the opened file in a SublimeREPL when the `f5` key is pressed.

What I need is a way to mimic the "Build" shortcut (`Ctrl+B`). This is: when the `f5` key is pressed, the current (opened) file should be *saved* before running the `project_venv_repl` command.

Can this instruction be added to the `project_venv_repl.py` script, or to the `command` line in the keybind definition?

Comment: Just add `self.view.run_command("save")` to your `run()` method.

Comment: Excellent, much simpler than I thought. Could you turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do anything fancy. If you just want to save the current view before running the REPL, edit your `ProjectVenvReplCommand` class's `run()` method (which is called when the `project_venv_repl` command is executed) and add the following line at the beginning:

```
self.view.run_command("save")
```

This will silently save the current view unless it has not been saved before, in which case a Save As... dialog will open just like usual.

If you want to save all open files in the window, you can use this code:

```
for open_view in self.view.window().views():
    open_view.run_command("save")
```

Comment: Matt, I came across an issue with this answer today that I hadn't noticed before. The `self.view.run_command("save")` command will save the current (opened) file perfectly, but not any other opened file with unsaved changes. I tried changing it to `self.view.run_command("save_all")` but it still only saves the current file before running. Can this be done at all?

Comment: @Gabriel see my edit - you just need to iterate over all the views in the current window.

Comment: Sorry to take this long to reply Matt, I had to do a clean OS install. I tried your solution, and although it does  save all the files with unsaved changes in the current view, it also shows a pop-up asking me to save the file from where I launched the REPL, or something similar:  `*REPL* [/home/gabriel/.pyenv/versions/test-env/bin/python -i -u /home/gabriel/Github/test.py]`. If I select *Cancel*, the REPL executes normally (with the unsaved files now saved), but that pop-up is not something I want to be closing every time I run my script. Perhaps I should open a new question?

Comment: I've made a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852604/save-all-files-before-running-custom-command-in-sublime3).