# Save all files before running custom command in Sublime3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

This is a derivative of this question I made some days ago [Save file before running custom command in Sublime3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39734390/1391441).

I've setup a custom keybind in Sublime Text 3:

```
{
    "keys": ["f5"],
    "command": "project_venv_repl"
}
```

to run the `project_venv_repl.py` script (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002696/1391441) to learn what it does):

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ProjectVenvReplCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    Starts a SublimeREPL, attempting to use project's specified
    python interpreter.
    """
    def run(self, edit, open_file='$file'):
        """Called on project_venv_repl command"""

        # Save all files before running REPL <---- THESE TWO LINES
        for open_view in self.view.window().views():
            open_view.run_command("save")

        cmd_list = [self.get_project_interpreter(), '-i', '-u']

        if open_file:
            cmd_list.append(open_file)

        self.repl_open(cmd_list=cmd_list)

    # Other functions...
```

This runs the opened file in a [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) when the `f5` key is pressed. The two lines below `# Save all files before running REPL` should save all opened files with unsaved changes, before running the REPL (as stated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39734918/1391441) to my previous question).

The lines work, ie: they save the files. But they also display two consecutive *Save* pop-ups, asking me to save the REPL (?):

```
*REPL* [/home/gabriel/.pyenv/versions/test-env/bin/python -i -u /home/gabriel/Github/test/test.py]
```

`test.py` is the file from where the script `project_venv_repl` was called. After I cancel both pop-ups, the script is executed correctly.

How can I get the `project_venv_repl` script to save all opened files with unsaved changes before executing, *without* displaying these annoying *Save* pop-ups?

(The idea behind all this is to mimic the behavior of `Ctrl+B`, which will save all unsaved files prior to building the script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to only save for files that are dirty and exist on disk.

```
# Write out every buffer (active window) with changes and a file name.
window = sublime.active_window()
for view in window.views():
    if view.is_dirty() and view.file_name():
        view.run_command('save')
```

I had a similar issue with [PHPUNITKIT](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-phpunit).

> **save_all_on_run: Only save files that exist on disk and have dirty buffers**
>
> Note: the "save_all_on_run" option no longer saves files that don't
>   exist on disk.
>
> The reason for this change is trying to save a file that doesn't exist
>   on disk prompts the user with a "save file" dialog, which is generally
>   not desired behaviour.
>
> Maybe another option "save_all_on_run_strict" option can be added
>   later that will try to save even the files that don't exist on disk.
>
> https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-phpunit/commit/3138e2b75a8fbb7a5cb8d7dacabc3cf72a77c1bf

Comment: What is `sublime.active_window()`? This results in `NameError: global name 'sublime' is not defined`. I only imported `sublime_plugin` in my script, what else should I import?

Comment: It's just a reference to the active window. You can use `self.view.window()` because you already have access to the view 's window from within your command. Whenever you need access to the window directly you can use `sublime.active_window()`, but yes you will need to `import sublime`.

Comment: Excellent, that does just what I needed. Thank you Gerard!